# get facebook user's profile picture without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently i am getting it this way https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture.

I searched and found that "A graph search endpoint without an access token." is not possible now.

**Questions**

So this image i am getting will be considered as graph search or not ?

If this is considered as graph search what would be other way to do this ?

I am not sure about it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you don’t need an access token to access the user profile picture (since those are always public on FB), and this has nothing to do with Graph search.

Comment: only time you need an access token is when the user_id is "me"; otherwise it doesn't know who that is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this facebook documentation, it clearly shows that you don't need any access token to get the picture.

LINK : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Answer (score 1):

To access profile picture of facebook profile you need user id or username of the user.

```
 public FacebookProfilePicture(String userid)
{

    String imageURL;
    bitmap = null;

    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + userid
            + "/picture?type=small";
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageURL)
        .getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Loading Picture FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Without access token you can get the basic information of a user.for example:
if we open this url 
graph.facebook.com/USERID then it will retrieve a JSON of the basic information.

Comment: I know i already tried it this way, but this is just to confirm that it might not get deprecated in short period of time. Do you have link of an official source where it's written that you can get profile picture without using access token.

Comment: This link may help you https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

This tells that access token is required only for rate limiting such that the 18+ content.